# How to insert data into two SQL Server tables in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have two tables, the first table is `Course` and this table contains three columns `Course_ID`, `Name_of_course`, `DeptID`; and the second table is `Department` and it has three columns `DeptID`, `DepName`, `College`.

I put a GridView to display the data that I will add it. But when I write the command to insert the data in both tables the data don't add. I used this command

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GridViewRow r = GridView1.SelectedRow;

        Dbclass db = new Dbclass();
        string s = "";

        DataTable dt = db.getTable(s);
        ddcollege.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[0]["College"].ToString();
        dddept.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[1]["DepName"].ToString();
        tbid.Text = r.Cells[0].Text;
        tbcourse_name.Text = r.Cells[1].Text;
        lblid.Text = tbid.Text;
        lberr.Text = "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lberr.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}

protected void btadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (tbid.Text == "")
        {
                lberr.Text = "Please input course id";
                return;
        }

        if (tbcourse_name.Text == "")
        {
                lberr.Text = "Please input course name";
                return;
        }

        string s = "Insert into Course(Course_ID,Name_of_course) values ('" + tbid.Text + "','" + tbcourse_name.Text + "')";

        s = "INSERT INTO Department (DepName,College,DeptID) VALUES ('"+dddept.SelectedValue+"','"+ddcollege.SelectedValue+"','"+tbdeptID.Text+"')";
        Dbclass db = new Dbclass();

        if (db.Run(s))
        {
                lberr.Text = "The data is added";
                lblid.Text = tbid.Text;
        }
        else
        { 
                lberr.Text = "The data is not added";
        }

        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            lberr.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Here is the Dbclass code:

```
public class Dbclass
{
    SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection();

    public Dbclass()
    {
        try
        {
            dbconn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=Fingerprint.mssql.somee.com;Initial Catalog=fingerprint;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Fingerprint_SQLLogin_1;Password=********";
            dbconn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    //----- run insert, delete and update
    public bool Run(String sql)
    {
        bool done= false;

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,dbconn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            done= true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        } 
        return done;
    }

    //----- run insert, delete and update
    public DataTable  getTable(String sql)
    {
        DataTable done = null;

        try
        {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, dbconn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                return ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return done;
    }
}
```

Thank you all

Comment: The logic is inside ***Dbclass***; it is hard to tell without seeing it.

Comment: First of all Avoid sql injection! Use Parameterized Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing I can see is you are assigning two different things to your "s" variable.

At this point db.Run(s) the value is "Insert into Department etc" and you have lost the first sql string you assigned to "s"

Try:

```
string s = "Insert into Course(Course_ID,Name_of_course) values ('" + tbid.Text + "','" + tbcourse_name.Text + "')";
        s += "INSERT INTO Department (DepName,College,DeptID) VALUES ('"+dddept.SelectedValue+"','"+ddcollege.SelectedValue+"','"+tbdeptID.Text+"')";
```

Notice the concatenation(+=). Otherwise as mentioned above using a stored procedure or entity framework would be a better approach. Also try to give your variables meaningful names. Instead of "s" use "insertIntoCourse" or something that describes what you are doing

Comment: it's working now, but the data does not display in GridView. Also, that data that I add in DeptID column only added in Department table, and DeptID in course table still null. is there a way when I add any data to deptID column it automatically  add in both tables

Comment: Get the query to work in SQL management studio first then it should be easy to bring it back into your code and add some variables. I would look at stored procedures though because strings of SQL statements are not used much anymore

Answer (score 0):

When a value is inserted into a table(Table1) and and value has to be entered to into another table(Table2) on insertion of value to Table1, you can use triggers.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189799.aspx

Answer (score 0):

"tbdeptID.Text" is giving you the department Id only right? You should be able to modify your first statement

string s = "Insert into Course(Course_ID,Name_of_course,***) values ('" + tbid.Text + "','" + tbcourse_name.Text + "',***)";

Please start running SQL Profiler, it is a good tool to see what is the actual query getting executed in server!